# can I control a WS2812B LED Strip with usb cable

Tags: usb, rgb, led

I have a WS2812B LED Strip that I'm planning to use in a small arduino project, but while I'm waiting for all the parts I wanted to miss around with the led strip, so is there a way to use the strip and controlling the colors using only a USB cable and a PC with a software without a dedicated controller?

Answer (score 0):

No.  USB ports on your PC can only send USB signals, they cannot send the specific protocol that a WS2812B needs.

Answer (score 0):

The PC can't control ws2812b led strip directly,if you want to control ws2812b led strip or [sk6812 led strip](http://www.normandled.com) by PC,you need to add Artnet controller.